# Jackson Deserializing a Map<String, String> where the value is Serialized object

Tags: jackson, json-deserialization

I'm facing a bit of problem. Basically I am calling a service it sends a response of something like this [core data L4-L11]:

```
 1. {
 2.  "Results" : {
 3.    "data" : [
 4.       {
 5.        "mapkey1" : "{
 6.          "sampleField" : {
 7.            "entity" : "value"
 8.          }
 9.        }",
10.        "mapkey2":"mapvalue2"
11.      }
12.    ],  
13.    "name" : "Results"
14.  }
15. }
```

I'm trying to get the above response into a Map<String, Object>, where the map will look something like this

```
<"mapkey1", "<serialized-object>">
<"mapkey2", "mapvalue2">
```

So far, I've been using Jackson to deserialize. The code I've been using

```
TreeNode tree = objectMapper.readTree(responseDescriptor.snapshotResponse());
response = tree.get("Results).get("data").get(0);

Map<String, String> map = objectMapper.convertValue(response, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```

Above code is throwing the exception, when executing line 1 of above code. [this is happening because the serialized object is store as string in the map, which is further serialized, you can see it in line-6 of the response]

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
```

Can anyone help me out in deserializing this ? Any leads appreciated!